# Weird tooltips in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, amd-graphics, system-settings, tooltip

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop (alongside Windows 7) and everything is working fine so far - but the tooltips in file explorer and system settings look weird (see 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVy5o.png)).

Did anyone have the same issue and is there a way to fix this? (It's not really important but nevertheless slightly annoying.)

If you need more information, please leave a comment.

My chip model is: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470

"About This Computer" in Ubuntu says: Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-38-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)

Comment: What graphics card or chip do you have? It could be because the chip is poorly supported, the system isn't updated (which may have a fix, but it also may not), or the driver for the graphics card/chip isn't installed yet. Try these and if the issue persists let us know.

Comment: The driver is definitely installed and I installed all OS updates that were available. I'm not completely sure how to check whether my graphics card drivers are up to date on Ubuntu, so I can't say whether newer drivers are available. The chip model is: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470.

Comment: I'm not sure, though, whether the graphics card actually is the problem because these tooltips are the only thing that looks strange - everything else looks like it's supposed to look like. That doesn't sound like a poorly supported chip to me.

Comment: I just checked the information provided by "About This Computer" in Ubuntu and it says: Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-38-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using default Ambiance theme you need to edit **gtk-widget.css** file of your theme. The best way is to copy original theme into your home directory to avoid problems with permissions.

If you don’t have it already create folder `.themes` in your home directory. Open **Files**, go to `/usr/share/themes` and copy folder `Ambiance` in to `~/.themes` folder. Rename the folder eg. *Ambiance Modified*.
Go to subfolder `gtk-3.0` and open the **gtk-widget.css** file with **Gedit**. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter "tooltip".

You need to replace the code:

```
background-image: -gtk-gradient (radial, center 0, 0, center 0, 0.8,
from (alpha (mix (@tooltip_bg_color, #ffffff, 0.2), 0.86)),
to (alpha (@tooltip_bg_color, 0.86)));
```

with the line:

```
background-color: @tooltip_bg_color;
```

I’m not very familiar with gtk gradients but something is obviously wrong with them. I replaced the gradients with solid color.

Save the file and apply the modified theme with **Unity Tweak Tools**.